# Web Scraping in R | Unable to extract information under a certain node using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to extract a bit of information under the node `/html/head/script[16]` from a website ([here](https://www.nykaa.com/biotique-bio-kelp-protein-shampoo-for-falling-hair-intensive-hair-growth-treatment-conf/p/357142?categoryId=1292&productId=357142&ptype=product&skuId=39934)) but am unable to do so.

```
nykaa <- "https://www.nykaa.com/biotique-bio-kelp-protein-shampoo-for-falling-hair-intensive-hair-growth-treatment-conf/p/357142?categoryId=1292&productId=357142&ptype=product&skuId=39934"

obj <- read_html(nykaa)

extracted_json <- obj %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "/html/head/script[16]") %>% 
  html_text(trim = TRUE)
```

Currently, my output for the above code is null. But I would like to extract the data under the above mentioned node in an organized manner.

Comment: It looks like the `xpath` you're using in the call to `html_node` is bad. Which bit(s) of information are you trying to extract?

Comment: @ulfelder I'm trying to extract features like price, quantity etc from the information present in that node. And I can't extract the Xpath below the one I've specified!

Comment: If I run `html_nodes(obj, xpath = "//html//head//script")`, I get a set of just 4 nodes. So there is no `script[16]`.

Comment: @ulfelder That's weird. If I search for "quantity" within Inspect Element and then copy the Xpath of tag within which quantity is present, I get "/html/head/script[16]"

Comment: I'm not an expert at this particular process, but I think the problem might be that the page is using Javascript to render the information you're after. So what you're getting from `rvest` is the call to Javascript rather than the result. Run `extracted_json <- obj %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//html//head//script") %>% html_text()` and then take a look at `extracted_json[3]` to see what I mean.

Comment: One possible solution to that problem: https://datascienceplus.com/scraping-javascript-rendered-web-content-using-r/

Comment: @ulfelder I did try this out. But as the html_node("/html/head/script[16]") returns null, the further steps do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to grab the javascript object inside that script tag and then pass to jsonlite and parse. You need to root around a bit to get what you want from that but it is all there

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)

p <- read_html('https://www.nykaa.com/biotique-bio-kelp-protein-shampoo-for-falling-hair-intensive-hair-growth-treatment-conf/p/357142?categoryId=1292&productId=357142&ptype=product&skuId=39934') %>% html_text()
all_data <- jsonlite::parse_json(str_match_all(p,'window\\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = (.*)')[[1]][,2])
```